# Merge two files and add computation and sorting the updated data in python

Tags: python, sorting

I need help to make the snippet below. I need to merge two files and performs computation on matched lines

I have **oldFile.txt** which contains old data and **newFile.txt** with an updated sets of data.

I need to to update the **oldFile.txt** based on the data in the **newFile.txt** and compute the changes in percentage. Any idea will be very helpful. Thanks in advance

```
from collections import defaultdict
num = 0
data=defaultdict(int)
with open("newFile.txt", encoding='utf8', errors='ignore') as f:
    for line in f:
        grp, pname, cnt, cat = line.split(maxsplit=3)
        data[(pname.strip(),cat.replace('\n','').strip(),grp,cat)]+=int(cnt)
        
sorteddata = sorted([[k[0],v,k[1],k[2]] for k,v in data.items()], key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)

for subl in sorteddata[:10]:
    num += 1
    line = " ".join(map(str, subl))
    print ("{:>5} -> {:>}".format(str(num), line))

    with open("oldFile.txt", 'a', encoding='utf8', errors='ignore') as l:
        l.write(" ".join(map(str, subl)) + '\n')
```

oldFile.txt

```
 #col1             #col2        #col3  #col4
 1,396 c15e89f2149bcc0cbd5fb204   4    HUH_Token (HUH)                      
   279 9e4d81c8fc15870b15aef8dc   3    BABY BNB (BBNB)                
   231 31b5c07636dab8f0909dbd2d   6    Buff Unicorn (BUFFUN...)             
   438 1c6bc8e962427deb4106ae06   8    Charge (Charge)                      
 2,739 6ea059a29eccecee4e250414   2    MAXIMACASH (MAXCAS...)
```

newFile.txt #-- updated data with additional lines not found in oldFile.txt

```
 #col1             #col2        #col3  #col4
 8,739 6ea059a29eccecee4e250414   60   MAXIMACASH (MAXCAS...)
   138 1c6bc8e962427deb4106ae06   50   Charge (Charge)                      
   860 31b5c07636dab8f0909dbd2d   40   Buff Unicorn (BUFFUN...)             
   200 9e4d81c8fc15870b15aef8dc   30   BABY BNB (BBNB)    #-- not found in the oldFile.txt
    20 5esdsds2sd15870b15aef8dc   30   CharliesAngel (CA)            
 1,560 c15e89f2149bcc0cbd5fb204   20   HUH_Token (HUH)
```

Need Improvement: #-- With additional columns (col5, col6) and sorted based on (col3) values

```
 #col1             #col2        #col3      #col4                #col5 (oldFile-newFile)   #col6 (oldFile-newFile)
 8,739 6ea059a29eccecee4e250414  62   MAXIMACASH (MAXCAS...)   2900.00 % (col3 2-60)    219.06 % (col1 2,739-8,739) 
   138 1c6bc8e962427deb4106ae06  58   Charge (Charge)           625.00 % (col3 8-50)    -68.49 % (col1   438-138)      
   860 31b5c07636dab8f0909dbd2d  46   Buff Unicorn (BUFFUN...)  566.67 % (col3 6-40)    272.29 % (col1   231-860)
   200 9e4d81c8fc15870b15aef8dc  33   BABY BNB (BBNB)           900.00 % (col3 3-30)    -28.32 % (col1   279-200) 
    20 5esdsds2sd15870b15aef8dc  30   CharliesAngel (CA)          0.00 % (col3 0-30)     20.00 % (col1   0-20) 
 1,560 c15e89f2149bcc0cbd5fb204  24   HUH_Token (HUH)           400.00 % (col3 4-20)     11.75 % (col1 1,396-1,560)
```

Comment: What have you done to even *attempt* to make these changes?

Comment: I made attempts yesterday and until now but my attempts didnt work sadly

Comment: I suggest adding `'r'` in your calls to `open` if your only reading a file, and `'w'` if you're only writing to a file. This will protect you against mistakes such as accidentally damaging a file that you wanted to read; and it will make your code easier to understand since it will be immediately obvious whether you're reading or writing.

Comment: Sooooo what is your question exactly? Is the code that you wrote not satisfactory? Why? Does it crash with an error message? Does it perform the wrong changes? What should it do and what is it doing instead?

Comment: Thank you. Its noted. Im not really an IT guy. The code just overwrite the oldFile.txt. What I wanted to accomplished is to update the oldFile.txt based on the newFile.txt data. No error with the code but output is wrong.

Comment: I think you should toss the reading and writing altogether. Unless you're having problems with those areas, refine your problem to simply the core issue - taking two multidimensional arrays and converting it to a single multidimensional array. The file read/write is straightforward. With your actual data conversion, what have you tried to do to merge the two?

Comment: @rbutrnz So you don't make a social faux pas in the future... 'IT' does not generally refer to the same skillset as a 'programmer'.

Comment: @NathanielFord well noted. Thank you very much.

Comment: Although if your colleagues ever learn that you're a "programmer", you'll definitely become the de facto "IT guy".

Comment: How 2900.00 % and 219.06 % are calculated?

Comment: @ferdy its from 2 MAXIMACASH (oldFile.txt) and 60 MAXIMACASH (newFile.txt). Its from 2 to 60 (2,900%)

Comment: @ferdy, I you have any suggestion that can still come up with the percentage computation, its very welcome.

Comment: @ferdy, 2900.00 % is based on col3 values while 219.06 % is based on col1 values

Comment: The value `625.00 % (from 8-50)` is wrong. Correct is 525.0%. I believe the general formula is `percentage_change = 100*(new-old)/old`. If old is zero, this is undefined. What value shall be used if old is zero? 0% or 100% or None or other values?

Comment: @ferdy, as for the zero values, perhaps it can just be set to 1 just to have the computation. Thank you.

Comment: All right I will attempt to solve it.

Comment: In col3 the values are added from old and new, but in col1 there is no change is this correct?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a sample code to output what you need.
I use the formula below to calculate pct change.
`percentage_change = 100*(new-old)/old`

If old is 0 it is changed to 1 to avoid division by zero error.

```
import pandas as pd


def read_file(fn):
    """
    Read file fn and convert data into a dict of dict.
    data = {pname1: {grp: grp1, pname: pname1, cnt: cnt1, cat: cat1},
            pname2: {gpr: grp2, ...} ...}
    """
    data = {}
    with open(fn, 'r') as f:
        for lines in f:
            line = lines.rstrip()
            grp, pname, cnt, cat = line.split(maxsplit=3)
            data.update({pname: {'grp': float(grp.replace(',', '')), 'pname': pname, 'cnt': int(cnt), 'cat': cat}})
            
    return data


def process_data(oldfn, newfn):  
    """
    Read old and new files, update the old file based on new file.
    Save output to text, and csv files.
    """
    # Get old and new data in dict.
    old = read_file(oldfn)
    new = read_file(newfn)

    # Update old data based on new data
    u_data = {}
    for ko, vo in old.items():
        if ko in new:
            n = new[ko]
            
            # Update cnt.
            old_cnt = vo['cnt']
            new_cnt = n['cnt']
            u_cnt = old_cnt + new_cnt

            # cnt change, if old is zero we set it to 1 to avoid division by zero error.
            tmp_old_cnt = 1 if old_cnt == 0 else old_cnt
            cnt_change = 100 * (new_cnt - tmp_old_cnt) / tmp_old_cnt

            # grp change
            old_grp = vo['grp']
            new_grp = n['grp']
            grp_change = 100 * (new_grp - old_grp) / old_grp

            u_data.update({ko: {'grp': n['grp'], 'pname': n['pname'], 'cnt': u_cnt, 'cat': n['cat'],
                                'cnt_change%': round(cnt_change, 2), 'grp_change%': round(grp_change, 2)}})

    # add new data to u_data, that is not in old data
    for kn, vn in new.items():
        if kn not in old:        
            # Since this is new item its old cnt is zero, we set it to 1 to avoid division by zero error.
            old_cnt = 1
            new_cnt = vn['cnt']
            cnt_change = 100 * (new_cnt - old_cnt) / old_cnt        

            # grp change is similar to cnt change
            old_grp = 1
            new_grp = vn['grp']
            grp_change = 100 * (new_grp - old_grp) / old_grp
            
            # Update new columns.
            vn.update({'cnt_change%': round(cnt_change, 2), 'grp_change%': round(grp_change, 2)})        
            u_data.update({kn: vn})
            
    # Create new data mydata list from u_data, and only extract the dict value.
    mydata = []
    for _, v in u_data.items():
        mydata.append(v)
        
    # Convert mydata into pandas dataframe to easier manage the data.
    df = pd.DataFrame(mydata)
    df = df.sort_values(by=['cnt'], ascending=False)  # sort on cnt column
    
    # Save to csv file.
    df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
    
    # Save to text file.
    with open('output.txt', 'w') as w:
        w.write(f'{df.to_string(index=False)}')
        
    # Print in console.    
    print(df.to_string(index=False))


# Start
oldfn = 'F:/Tmp/oldFile.txt'
newfn = 'F:/Tmp/newFile.txt'
process_data(oldfn, newfn)
```

Console output:

```
   grp                    pname  cnt                      cat  cnt_change%  grp_change%
8739.0 6ea059a29eccecee4e250414   62   MAXIMACASH (MAXCAS...)      2900.00       219.06
 138.0 1c6bc8e962427deb4106ae06   58          Charge (Charge)       525.00       -68.49
 860.0 31b5c07636dab8f0909dbd2d   46 Buff Unicorn (BUFFUN...)       566.67       272.29
 200.0 9e4d81c8fc15870b15aef8dc   33          BABY BNB (BBNB)       900.00       -28.32
  20.0 5esdsds2sd15870b15aef8dc   30       CharliesAngel (CA)      2900.00      1900.00
1560.0 c15e89f2149bcc0cbd5fb204   24          HUH_Token (HUH)       400.00        11.75
```

text output:

```
   grp                    pname  cnt                      cat  cnt_change%  grp_change%
8739.0 6ea059a29eccecee4e250414   62   MAXIMACASH (MAXCAS...)      2900.00       219.06
 138.0 1c6bc8e962427deb4106ae06   58          Charge (Charge)       525.00       -68.49
 860.0 31b5c07636dab8f0909dbd2d   46 Buff Unicorn (BUFFUN...)       566.67       272.29
 200.0 9e4d81c8fc15870b15aef8dc   33          BABY BNB (BBNB)       900.00       -28.32
  20.0 5esdsds2sd15870b15aef8dc   30       CharliesAngel (CA)      2900.00      1900.00
1560.0 c15e89f2149bcc0cbd5fb204   24          HUH_Token (HUH)       400.00        11.75
```

csv output:

```
grp,pname,cnt,cat,cnt_change%,grp_change%
8739.0,6ea059a29eccecee4e250414,62,MAXIMACASH (MAXCAS...),2900.0,219.06
138.0,1c6bc8e962427deb4106ae06,58,Charge (Charge),525.0,-68.49
860.0,31b5c07636dab8f0909dbd2d,46,Buff Unicorn (BUFFUN...),566.67,272.29
200.0,9e4d81c8fc15870b15aef8dc,33,BABY BNB (BBNB),900.0,-28.32
20.0,5esdsds2sd15870b15aef8dc,30,CharliesAngel (CA),2900.0,1900.0
1560.0,c15e89f2149bcc0cbd5fb204,24,HUH_Token (HUH),400.0,11.75
```

Answer (score 3):

Just to give a [convtools](https://github.com/westandskif/convtools) based alternative solution, where you may find useful pieces:

```py
from convtools import conversion as c
from convtools.contrib.tables import Table

# your percentage change calculation
def c_change(column_name):
    return c.if_(
        c.and_(
            c.col(f"{column_name}_LEFT"),
            c.col(f"{column_name}_RIGHT").is_not(None),
        ),
        (
            (c.col(f"{column_name}_RIGHT") - c.col(f"{column_name}_LEFT"))
            / c.col(f"{column_name}_LEFT")
            * 100.0
        ).pipe(round, 2),
        None,
    )

prepare_columns = {
    "COLUMN_0": c.col("COLUMN_0").as_type(float),
    "COLUMN_2": c.col("COLUMN_2").as_type(float),
}
dialect = Table.csv_dialect(delimiter="\t")

sorted_rows = sorted(
    Table.from_csv("tmp1.csv", dialect=dialect)
    .update(**prepare_columns)
    .join(
        Table.from_csv(
            "tmp2.csv",
            dialect=dialect,
        ).update(**prepare_columns),
        on=["COLUMN_1", "COLUMN_3"],
        how="full",
    )
    .update(
        COLUMN_4=c_change("COLUMN_2"),
        COLUMN_5=c_change("COLUMN_0"),
        COLUMN_2=c.col("COLUMN_2_RIGHT"),
        COLUMN_0=c.col("COLUMN_0_RIGHT"),
    )
    .take(
        "COLUMN_0",
        "COLUMN_1",
        "COLUMN_2",
        "COLUMN_3",
        "COLUMN_4",
        "COLUMN_5",
    )
    .into_iter_rows(tuple),
    key=lambda row: row[2],
    reverse=True,
)

Table.from_rows(sorted_rows).into_csv("tmp_result.csv", dialect=dialect)
```

Results in:

```
COLUMN_0    COLUMN_1    COLUMN_2    COLUMN_3    COLUMN_4    COLUMN_5
8739.0  6ea059a29eccecee4e250414    60.0    MAXIMACASH (MAXCAS...)  2900.0  219.06
138.0   1c6bc8e962427deb4106ae06    50.0    Charge (Charge) 525.0   -68.49
860.0   31b5c07636dab8f0909dbd2d    40.0    Buff Unicorn (BUFFUN...)    566.67  272.29
200.0   9e4d81c8fc15870b15aef8dc    30.0    BABY BNB (BBNB) 900.0   -28.32
20.0    5esdsds2sd15870b15aef8dc    30.0    CharliesAngel (CA)      
1560.0  c15e89f2149bcc0cbd5fb204    20.0    HUH_Token (HUH) 400.0   11.75
```